# JPA makes MSSQL Transactions lock

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa, glassfish, ejb-3.0

We have a Java EE app running on Glassfish 3.0.1 that uses EJBs, JPA along with Hibernate as implementation and have MS SQL Server 2008 R2 as database engine with JTDS as JDBC driver. We have chosen Optimistic Locking strategy by specifying @version field on every entities. The DB accesses can be concurrent and lots of db reads might be requested during JTA transactions.

We tried to make our transactions as quick as possible by breaking them down by little unit of work.

Unfortunately we are at a situation where we get database locks that never ends. We can see from MS SQL Server Activity Monitor that one transaction locks others, and that particular one never stops until we kill it. If we look at the statement it is an insert on an history table that blocks other transactions that simply are select on an other table having no relation to the history one.

First question, why SQL Server locks tables since we are in optimistic locking strategy? How can we prevent that behavior?

Comment: This is likely not a SQL Server problem but a problem with the configuration of your app. Why does the insert "never end"? Probably it is blocked, too? On what? Try enabling the two snapshot isolation settings on the database.